# Trouble joining lists together

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm having trouble joining two lists properly.

```
def option_6():
  global main_arr                                                       
  print('List intially:', main_arr)                                 
  arr_str = input('Enter new list\n')           
  new_arr = arr_str                                     
  main_arr = join(main_arr, new_arr)                                    
  print('Lists joined')                                             
  print('List after joining new list:', main_arr)
```

here's my function

```
def join(arr1, arr2):
  new_arr = arr1                                                    
  for item in arr2:                                                 
    new_arr.append(item)                                            
  return new_arr
```

the end result after adding a new element and creating a new list is that the joined list created reads the entered element as `['1stList', '2', 'n', 'd', 'L', 'i', 's', 't']`

instead of

```
['1stList`, '2ndList']
```

Comment: If you want to join two lists together use `list.extend(other_list)` which will modify the first list to append all elements of the other list to it. Or concatenate the lists together and form a new one `new_list = list1 + list2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through characters of string. Basically `new_arr` is a string and not an array.

**Solution:**

Ask the user to enter comma separated values. And then you can do `new_arr = arr_str.split(',')`.

Comment: Is there a way to go about `split()` without using it?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `input('Enter new list\n')` returns a string instead of a list.

btw you can use `list1 + list2` to join two list

Comment: How do I fix that? Should I make `arr_str` a list instead?

Comment: Yes. Make `new_arr = [arr_str]` in `def option_6()`.

Comment: Just saw your edit. True! But I need to ask the user to create a new list for the program to create a list out of then join it with the first list.

Comment: Ask the user to enter comma separated values. And then you can do `new_arr = arr_str.split(',')`.

Answer (score 0):

The code

> arr_str = input('Enter new list\n')

read '2ndList' as a string rather than a list ['2ndList']. Then when you iterate the string, you will get why would it be that form.